# After adding the header getting the blank pdf page in wicked_pdf Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

My code working perfect without header, but after adding header I am getting the blank pdf page. Please solve my issue

```
def show
    @resume = current_user.resume
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{ }
      format.pdf do 
         render template: 'student/resumes/show', 
                pdf: "#{current_user.first_name}.pdf",
                # :header => { :content => render_to_string({:template => 'student/resumes/header.pdf.erb'})}
                header:  {
                          html: {           
                          template: 'student/resumes/header'},
                          layout: 'pdf.erb',
                          handlers: [:erb],
                          formats: [:pdf] 
                          }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same issue i also faced with the code so I tried with lots of combinations but at the last i found the following solutions which worked for me

Followed the proper HTML DOM format which works perfectly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title></title>
    <link href=“https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700” rel=“stylesheet”>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag ‘pdf’ %>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above is Example for Header

Also I added the following property in the controller to generate PDF

```
          render template: 'backend/report_result/report',
             pdf: "test",
             header:  {   html: {            template: 'backend/report_result/header'}},
             margin: { top: 30, bottom: 20, left: 25, right: 25 }
```

Make sure to use all properties proper along with the view with pdf.erb format

Answer (score 1):

Your closing brackets are in the wrong place. header - html should contain all those other keys

```html
def show
    @resume = current_user.resume
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{ }
      format.pdf do 
         render template: 'student/resumes/show', 
                pdf: "#{current_user.first_name}.pdf",
                # :header => { :content => render_to_string({:template => 'student/resumes/header.pdf.erb'})}
                header:  {
                          html: {           
                          template: 'student/resumes/header',
                          layout: 'pdf.erb',
                          handlers: [:erb],
                          formats: [:pdf] 
                          }}
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: ***************WICKED***************
  Rendered student/resumes/show.pdf.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered student/resumes/header.pdf.erb (5279.1ms)
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a extra page in your pdf when pdf generate with wicked pdf, then

Simply put a division at last of your html code (or you may put a div according to your code). like :

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <% if question.id == @questions.last.id %>
    <div></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

After adding a division in your html.put the following line in your css:

```
div.alwaysbreak { page-break-before: always; }
div.nobreak:before { clear:both; }
div.nobreak{ page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

It works for me